# input for def in if statement trouble

Tags: python

When i start this code i want it to restart def start() inside my if part and make it so i can input 1 again and itll post it again but that doesnt work. I really dont know why and i would appreciate the help. I need this answered fairly quickly so i can finish my assignment. If it helps im using python in visual studio 2017.

```
def start():
    print("\nWhat would you like to do?")
    print("1) Call out to someone")
    print("2) Stand up")
    print("3) Touch your head")
    print("4) Sleep\n")
    choice = input("Make your decision!: ")
    return choice

choice = start()

if choice=="1":
    print("You call out")
    print("No one came")
    print(start())


else:
   print("nope")
```

Comment: If this is Python 2.x, use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `while` loop. If you really want to try to figure the assignment out by yourself, stop reading now, otherwise:

```
def start():
    print("\nWhat would you like to do?")
    print("1) Call out to someone")
    print("2) Stand up")
    print("3) Touch your head")
    print("4) Sleep\n")
    choice = input("Make your decision!: ")
    return choice

choice = start()

while choice=="1":
    print("You call out")
    print("No one came")
    choice = start()

print("nope")
```

The indented block after `while` gets executed as long as the expression `choice=="1"` evaluates to `True`.

1. The return value of function `start` is assigned to the variable `choice` (right after your function defintion).
2. If the expression `choice=="1"` evaluates to `False` (anything other than 1 was entered by the user), the block under while loop *won't* get executed and the program prints "nope".
3. If the expression `choice=="1"` evalutes to `True` (1 was entered by the user), the block under the while loop *will* be executed (print, and assign the return value of function `start` to the variable `choice` again).
4. The expression after the `while` will be evaluated again.

Comment: @alexisdevarennes Why not?

Comment: @alexisdevarennes Before and in the loop `start()` is called and `choice` is set with the result and the while-loop evaluates `choice` on each turn. No problem.

Comment: Wow im tired. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to wrap the rest of the logic in a function and call it at the end again instead of `start()`

```
def question():

    def start():
        print("\nWhat would you like to do?")
        print("1) Call out to someone")
        print("2) Stand up")
        print("3) Touch your head")
        print("4) Sleep\n")
        choice = input("Make your decision!: ")

        return choice

    choice = start()

    if str(choice) == "1":
        print("You call out")
        print("No one came")
        question()
    else:
        print("nope")

question()
```

Comment: Wrapping the code in functions is generally good practice but won't help with the particular problem.

Comment: Why? Hed like to input the number again. This will run the code again. Explain?

Comment: Updated, this works both 2.7 and 3>. Casting choice to str()

Comment: C0DY shows how it can work (except for the `input` on Python 2.x).

Comment: Recursion is general a poor substitute for a loop. No the OP probably won't run this code the 9000+ times required to overflow the call stack, but it's better practice to use the right construct for the job: a loop.

Comment: @ChristianDean Please explain why using a while loop would be better than using a function and a nested function and calling it recursively? Anyway, this doesn't change the fact that other answers still do not solve OPs problem

Comment: @alexisdevarennes Depending how deep the recursion becomes a <name of this website> can happen :)

Comment: @alexisdevarennes Well probably the biggest problem with using recursion vs a normal loop is that recursion uses much more memory.  Each time a function is call, a new frame must be pushed on the call stack.

Comment: Sure, true. But not something I'd consider for OPs usecase.

Comment: @alexisdevarennes It is not necessarily about efficiency, it also about good practices,  any loop can be translated to recursion to a certain degree, but using the right approach is what defines good programmers. Now, even if in my opinion the `while` loop is more pythonic, I agree with you that both works and are acceptable. I would still recommend using iteration in this case mainly for readability.